# EditorGUILayout.LabelField почему не работает Tooltip при Play

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Имея обычный код, пытаюсь переопределить рисование компонента.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(UDebugBox))]

public class UDebugBoxEditor : Editor
{
     public override void OnInspectorGUI()
     {
           EditorGUILayout.LabelField(new GUIContent("Text","Tooltip"), GUILayout.Width(300));
     }
}
```

**Проблема**: не видно Tooltip при наведении на данный Label во время Play

**Вопрос**: как это починить?

Comment: Проверил ваш код у себя - все работает.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а какая версия юнити у вас? .NET какой?

Comment: 2018.2.2f1, .NET 3.5.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а во время запуска приложения(если в редактор нажать кнопку Play) подсказка появляется?

Comment: Нет, в play mode не работает, да и не должно по идее. А зачем вам тултипы во время рантайма?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker хочется смотреть тип значения в Tooltip, а не выводить его с помощью : и подобного, засоряя пространство, т.к постоянно это не нужно

Comment: Без костылей тут не обойтись - только Editor.Repaint поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такова механика Unity. В инспекторе при Play подсказки у полей отображаться не будут, только если Play не запущен или стоит Pause.

Поэтому либо использовать костыли, либо искать другой способ выполнить свою задачу